# Find a closed curve where $F(x,y,z)=(y,x,x)$ closed line integral isn't 0.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, line-integrals

Given the function $F(x,y,z)=(y,x,x)$, I have to show it isn't conservative and find a close curve where it isn't equal to 0.

It was easy to show that $D_1F_3\neq D_3F_1$, but I can't find an easy curve that isn't 0. I tried unit circle but it equals to zero.

Watching the plot I can't figure it out. In general, I don't know how to solve this when I'm in $\mathbb{R^3}.$

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the circle $C : t \mapsto (\cos t, 0, \sin t)$.

You have $C^\prime(t)=(-\sin t, 0, \cos t)$ and

$$\int_C F.dr =\int_0^{2\pi} \cos^2 t \ dt >0$$

Comment: Great! I tried with a circle too and failed, thanks for the answer!.